# Creating arrays quickly from a dataframe with lots of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

1. I have a large dataframe (imported from a csv file via pandas) with lots of values (259 rows × 27 columns). The index are months starting from January 1996 through to July 2017.

[Image of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx1Cl.png)

2. I want to sort every column by year e.g. K37L: 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000 etc; K37M: 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000 etc.
3. This is my current code:

> ```
> #Importing CSV
> import pandas as pd
> import numpy as np
> df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0, skipinitialspace=True)
>
> #Calling a column
> K37L = df['K37L']
>
> #Filtering this column by year (from 1996 to 2017)
> K37L96 = K37L.filter(regex = '1996', axis = 0); npK37L96 = np.array(K37L96)
> ...
> ...
> ...
> K37L17 = K37L.filter(regex = '2017', axis = 0); npK37L17 = np.array(K37L17)
> ```

4. This produces what I want: [K37L filtered by 1996](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALj3e.png)

However, this is a tedious process, since I have to type out all the years and the column names to get what I want, it will take ages. Is there a faster / more elegant way to do this?

EDIT: Here is the df.head() output as requested:

```
          K37L  K37M  K37N  K37P  K37Q  K37R  K37S  K37T  K37U  K37V  ...   \
1996 Jan  78.9  79.4  71.7  36.7   0.0  88.7  94.1  90.7  80.2  98.9  ...    
1996 Feb  79.3  81.0  72.7  36.7   0.0  88.7  94.3  90.9  79.8  98.7  ...    
1996 Mar  79.8  80.4  72.7  36.7   0.0  89.0  94.6  91.0  79.6  98.6  ...    
1996 Apr  80.4  80.7  72.9  36.7   0.0  89.0  94.6  91.3  79.2  97.9  ...    
1996 May  80.6  80.7  72.9  36.7   0.0  89.1  94.7  91.9  79.2  96.6  ...    

          K385  K386   K387  K388  K389  K38A  K38B  K38C  K38D  K38E  
1996 Jan  70.9  78.7  257.8  83.9  79.7  92.2  73.8  86.4  79.6  74.0  
1996 Feb  70.7  78.7  257.2  83.9  79.8  92.6  73.7  86.6  79.9  73.9  
1996 Mar  70.9  78.7  257.3  83.9  80.1  92.6  73.8  87.2  80.1  74.0  
1996 Apr  70.8  78.9  256.6  83.9  80.4  92.7  73.9  87.9  80.7  74.0  
1996 May  70.9  78.9  256.3  83.9  80.5  92.9  73.9  88.0  80.7  74.1  

[5 rows x 27 columns]
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your data. Just copy-paste the output of `df.head()` as raw text...

Comment: Apologies, I've added the df.head() output onto the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
np.random.seed(458)
cols = ['K37L', 'K37M', 'K37N', 'K37P', 'K37Q', 'K37R', 'K37S', 'K37T', 'K37U','K37V', 'K37W', 'K37X', 'K37Y', 'K37Z', 'K382', 'K383', 'K384', 'K385', 'K386', 'K387', 'K388', 'K389', 'K38A', 'K38B', 'K38C', 'K38D', 'K38E']
idx = pd.date_range('1996-01-01', periods=259, freq='MS').strftime('%Y %b')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(259,27)), index=idx, columns=cols)
print (df.head(3))
          K37L  K37M  K37N  K37P  K37Q  K37R  K37S  K37T  K37U  K37V  ...   \
1996 Jan     8    13    18     1     6     2     1    11    13     0  ...    
1996 Feb    12     0    14     0    11     0     1    10     3     4  ...    
1996 Mar     5     8     8     8     5     5     2     8     1     7  ...    

          K385  K386  K387  K388  K389  K38A  K38B  K38C  K38D  K38E  
1996 Jan    18    16     0    11    18    18    11    18    11    17  
1996 Feb     9    12    15     7     7     0    17     3     6     7  
1996 Mar    13     9     0     9     2    17    13     1    12     9  

[3 rows x 27 columns]
```

Create `Datetimeindex` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y %b')
print (df.head(3))
            K37L  K37M  K37N  K37P  K37Q  K37R  K37S  K37T  K37U  K37V  ...   \
1996-01-01     8    13    18     1     6     2     1    11    13     0  ...    
1996-02-01    12     0    14     0    11     0     1    10     3     4  ...    
1996-03-01     5     8     8     8     5     5     2     8     1     7  ...    

            K385  K386  K387  K388  K389  K38A  K38B  K38C  K38D  K38E  
1996-01-01    18    16     0    11    18    18    11    18    11    17  
1996-02-01     9    12    15     7     7     0    17     3     6     7  
1996-03-01    13     9     0     9     2    17    13     1    12     9  

[3 rows x 27 columns]
```

So for select by yars use [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) and for select column `[]` (same syntax):

```
#seelcting rows with year 2000
print (df['2000'])
            K37L  K37M  K37N  K37P  K37Q  K37R  K37S  K37T  K37U  K37V  ...   
2000-01-01    12    15     8    14     2     0    17     0     8    14  ...    
2000-02-01    14    10    11     4    18     1     3    12     9    11  ...    
2000-03-01     4     5    17    16    13     6    18     6    12    12  ...    
2000-04-01     2    15     3     5     6     6    17     3     1     3  ...    
2000-05-01     6    14    14     9     4     0     4    10    14    15  ...    


#selecting column K37P
print (df['K37P'])
1996-01-01     1
1996-02-01     0
1996-03-01     8
1996-04-01    11
1996-05-01    14
1996-06-01    12
1996-07-01    12
1996-08-01    14
1996-09-01     2
1996-10-01     1
```

For selecting both first select column and then year:

```
print (df['K37L']['2000'])
2000-01-01    12
2000-02-01    14
2000-03-01     4
2000-04-01     2
2000-05-01     6
2000-06-01    10
2000-07-01     2
2000-08-01    13
2000-09-01    18
2000-10-01     4
2000-11-01    12
2000-12-01    11
Name: K37L, dtype: int32
```

For numpy array use:

```
print (df['K37L']['2000'].values)
[12 14  4  2  6 10  2 13 18  4 12 11]
```

If need dictionary of arrays by years:

Then select `year`s by [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) and last convert to array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) to `dictionary`:

```
d = {x: df[str(x)].values for x in range(1996, 2018)}

print (d[2000])
[[12 15  8 14  2  0 17  0  8 14 17 15  2  3 14 17 19  2  8  7  5  7 12 13
  17  7  4]
 [14 10 11  4 18  1  3 12  9 11  8  3 12 19 19 15  7 19 14 12  5 19 14 15
   7 11  7]
 [ 4  5 17 16 13  6 18  6 12 12  7 15  3 16  2 18 14 18 15  8  5  9  3  7
```

Comment: Okay I just tried this, this is what I get: https://i.imgur.com/AfgZK0j.png

I'm not sure if this is right. I can see that there is some sort of separation of months and years which is great, but then I don't understand what all those labels mean

Comment: OK, do you need `2d` array?

Comment: Yes actually I do! is it possible to get a 2d array from all that?

Comment: I create answer, it is what you want?

Comment: It's great jezrael, but is it possible to filter by year? Oh sorry I didn't read the next steps! Let me try it and I'll get back to you :)

Comment: Wow cool! How about filtering by the column name (K37L, K37M) etc?

Comment: So for example I can change a = df['2012'].values to a = df['K37L'].values but it shows K37L from 1996 to 2017; I would just want K37L from January 1996 to December 1996. If I do a = df['K37L'], is there a way to just select the first 12 values,  then the next 12 etc which can be used as the "years"?

Comment: Sorry, why need numpy arrays? ot better using datafarme for some setting?

Comment: I would like to use numpy arrays because I later want to subtract the values of 2007 from 2006 (just an example). I just notice you updated your answer so I will give that a try!

Comment: OK, so please check edit of my answer, I hope it help yuo.

Comment: Just tried it, it's fantastic jezrael. I am amazed how you managed that. Your answer is very useful and I hope many others will also find it helpful too! Thanks!